# How to extract matching keywords from two columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, text-extraction

I have two columns in a dataframe both are strings where column1 have some matching keywords in column2. I want to extract those matching keyword from column1 and column2 in a new column.

```
df['column3']=df.column1.apply(lambda x : df.column2[df.column2.str.contains(x)]
```

I am expecting the output something like this

```
column1                     column2                 column3
A girl is going to market   girl market school      girl market
A girl is going to school   girl market school      girl school
The sky is blue in color    sky blue orange color   sky blue color
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `apply`

**Ex:**

```
df["column3"] = df.apply(lambda x: " ".join(i for i in x["column2"].split() if i in x["column1"]),axis=1) 
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                     column1                column2         column3
0  A girl is going to market     girl market school     girl market
1  A girl is going to school     girl market school     girl school
2   The sky is blue in color  sky blue orange color  sky blue color
```

Answer (score 3):

using [np.intersect1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)

```
df['column3'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(np.intersect1d(x['column1'].split(),x['column2'].split())), axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
                     column1                    column2         column3
0  A girl is going to market         girl market school     girl market
1  A girl is going to school         girl market school     girl school
2   The sky is blue in color      sky blue orange color  blue color sky
```

if order matters

```
 df['column3'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(np.array(x['column1'].split())[np.in1d(x['column1'].split(),x['column2'].split())]), axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
                     column1                    column2         column3
0  A girl is going to market         girl market school     girl market
1  A girl is going to school         girl market school     girl school
2   The sky is blue in color      sky blue orange color  sky blue color
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using the intersection (`&`) of `sets`:

```
df['column3'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(set(x['column1'].split()) &
                                            set(x['column2'].split())), axis=1)
```

[out]

```
                     column1                column2         column3
0  A girl is going to market     girl market school     market girl
1  A girl is going to school     girl market school     girl school
2   The sky is blue in color  sky blue orange color  sky color blue
```